# how to submit a form inside the infowindow of google maps using ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

below is my code for submitting a form inside the infowindow, but when i click on submit button, the page gets reloaded and nothing happens. if i remove the script of ajax part of submitting the form using php post method, it is working fine. my idea to do it with ajax is that i dont want my marker to go off on submitting the form. i want it right there.
below is my code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#mylocation_form").submit(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#make_me_live").html("<img src='images/loader3.gif' />submitting...");
            var mylocation=$("#mylocation").val();
            if(mylocation=="")
            {
                $("#make_me_live").show().html("Cannot be empty");
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"mylocation.php",
                    data:"mylocation="+mylocation,
                       success:function(data){
                        if(data==0)
                        {
                            $("#make_me_live").html("Update not Successfull :(");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#make_me_live").html("Update successfull :)");
                        }
                    }
                 });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is my contentstring for infowindo

```
var contentstring = '<div id="infowindow_photo">' + '<img src="upload_pic/' + asd + '" height="100%" width="100%"/>' + '</div>'
                    + '<div id="infowindow_name">' + '<p><b>' + fname + ' ' + lname + '</b></p>' + '</div>'
                    + '<form id="mylocation_form" >'
                    + '<input type="text" name="mylocation" id="mylocation" style="height:50px; width:300px; outline:none;"/>'
                    //+ '<br />' + 'upload a photo' + '<input type="file" name="files[]" />'
                    + '<br />' + '<input type="submit" id="infowindow_submit" name="submit" value ="submit"/>'
                    + '</form>'
                    + '<div id="infowindow_menu">' + '</div>';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentstring 

    });

and this is my php code
<?php
    session_start();
    $usname=$_SESSION['username'];
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","********");
    mysql_select_db("anurag");

    $mylocation=$_POST["mylocation"];
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM members WHERE username='$usname' ");
    $row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
    $asd=$row1['uid'];
    $image_name = "temp_map";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO notifications VALUES('$asd','$mylocation',NOW(),'$image_name')";

    if(!mysql_query($sql))
             {
            die('Error :'.mysql_error());
        }
        else
        {
            $find=mysql_num_rows($sql);

                    echo $find;
        }

?>
```

please help me, its not working fine and i dont know what is the problem with thix ajax and jquery code

Comment: I'll clap the one who edits this question to format the code correctly ;)

Comment: thanks a ton whoever has done it. :)    i m really sry i dnt know how to write it in a correct format

Comment: The page reloads because you have some error in your javascript code. To see that error, press F12 to open console and see inside the error. This error may be seen momentarily and disappears after reloading.

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.          see this is the error which is coming on submitting the button. dont know what to do. i m using event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

You'd better have to prevent the form `submit` event instead of the button `click` event.

So instead of this:

```
$("#infowindow_submit").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
```

do this:

```
$("#mylocation_form").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
```

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: no it is also not working. tried it many time. i wrote it like this only and then checked but it was not working. so i changed it to the submit button click event.